# base64 decoding from file column

Tags: awk, base64, getline

I have a file, every line with 6 columns separated by ",". Last column is zipped and encoded in base 64. Output file should be column 3 and column 6(decoded/unzipped).

I tried to do this by

> ***awk -F',' '{"echo "$6" | base64 -di | gunzip"  | getline x;print $3,x }' OFS=',' inputfile.csv >outptfile_decoded.csv***

The result for the first lines is ok, but after some lines the decode output is the same as the line before. It seems that decoding & unzipping hungs, but I didn't get error message.

Singe decode/unzipping works fine i.e.

> echo "H4sIAAAAAAAAA7NJTkuxs0lMLrEztNEHUTZAgcy8tHw7m7zSXLuS1BwrbRNjMzMTc3MDAzMDG32QqE1uSWVBqh2QB2HYlCYX2xnb6IMoG324ASCWHQAaafi1YQAAAA==" | base64 -di | gunzip

What can be the reason for this effect? (there are no error messages).
Is there another way which works reliable?

Comment: check your line endings, if copied the file from Windows environment do `dos2unix`

Answer (score 1):

without a test case difficult to recommend anything.  Here is a working script with input data

> create a test data file

```
$ while read f; do echo $f,$(echo $f | gzip -f | base64); done < <(seq 5) | tee file.g
1,H4sIAJhBuVkAAzPkAgBT/FFnAgAAAA==
2,H4sIAJhBuVkAAzPiAgCQr3xMAgAAAA==
3,H4sIAJhBuVkAAzPmAgDRnmdVAgAAAA==
4,H4sIAJhBuVkAAzPhAgAWCCYaAgAAAA==
5,H4sIAJhBuVkAAzPlAgBXOT0DAgAAAA==
```

> and decode

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} 
             {cmd="echo "$2" | base64 -di | gunzip"; cmd | getline v; print $1,v}' file.g
1,1
2,2
3,3
4,4
5,5
```

Comment: I perform a testfile with 5000 entrys, when running decode I always get `1019,1019
awk: (FILENAME=file.g FNR=1020) fatal: cannot open pipe `echo H4sIAJ1zuVkAAzM0MDLgAgCZcDSyBQAAAA== | base64 -di | gunzip' (Too many open files)`

Comment: When I tested it with my own input file`(which includes 287000 lines, decoded entries have max 95 signs)` I got no error messages but having the `same effects as discribed in my starting question`